# Java Swing: JLabel Text Not Appearing on Screen

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to get a name input from the `Scanner` and display that on the screen through a `JLabel`. However, it is not appearing. The button that I made appears, but the label does not. Am I missing something?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 

public class MyProgram {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creating instance of JFrame
        
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Generate Password");
        b1.setBounds(90, 100, 180, 40);
        f.add(b1);
        b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        b1.setOpaque(true);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?"); 
        String name = sc.nextLine(); 
        JLabel n = new JLabel(); 
        n.setBounds(400, 100, 30, 30);
        n.setText(name + "'s Password Generator!");
        f.add(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont mix console-based `Scanner` with Swing. Use a `JTextField` to read your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're mixing a GUI- with a Console-Application. Is this really what you want?
2. You're `nulling` the Layout of your `JFrame`. Why do you do this? You basically always need layouting. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) guide.

Your `JLabel` is indeed showing. Try to resize your `JFrame` after you typed in your name, you should see your `JLabel` then. The `JLabel` will always appear, if you call `setVisible(true)` at the end of your program. This is because your `JFrame` gets painted when you call `setVisible(true)`. If you add another component to it, the `JFrame` is not repainted. If you resize it, it will be repainted.

However, you should have a look at [basic Java Swing tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html).